# Photoshop "could not fill because the current canvas size does not match that of the history state"

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have selected an area of a photo using the **Select > Color Range** and **Magic Wand** tools. I then pressed `CTRL-J` to copy the selection to a new layer. Now I am trying to fill the layer with a solid color. I can't do this either with `ALT-SHIFT-BACKSPACE` or `Edit > Fill` because I get this error:

> Could not fill because the current canvas size does not match that of
>   the history state

I've come across this before (although not so often with ancient versions of Photoshop) but have no idea how to get past this obstacle to finish my work.

Comment: Did you resize the canvas in the meantime?

Comment: I may have. Apart from the error message suggesting this might be related, I don't see why that would prevent me from filling a layer with a solid colour. I ended up pasting the whole thing into a new file where I could fill to my heart's content.

Comment: If that solves your problem, write it as an answer and accept it to show to others  there's a workaround.

Comment: I'd like to know how to avoid the error in future. It's not a complex operation and shouldn't be happening. Creating a new file is a heavy-handed solution.

Comment: I could not find other info about this error on the Web. Perhaps it's just another bug

Comment: I suspect this was a bug in PS (Windows 10) last year. I haven't seen it recently and have just tried to replicate it without success. So if anyone else gets this with a current PS version, tell us.